# Programming thunderbird Email Client?

Tags: java, python, ruby, scripting, thunderbird

Anyone has C#/Ruby/Python/Java or Perl scripts to get all the emails in a folder in Thunderbird client and download all the attachments?

I have more than 200 resumes as attachment kept in Resumes folder of thunderbird and I need to download the attachment and categories them. Any API reference to program thunderbird would be great..

I found this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs but I am looking for specific code samples..

Other references

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/pyxpcom

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using existing tools, instead of writing your own, you could give the [Thunderbird Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/) [AttachmentExtractor](http://www.eviljeff.com/?page=moz-extensions) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

How To Bulk Export Thunderbird Email & Attachments

http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-bulk-export-thunderbird-email-attachments/